# ¿Cómo muestro el correo en un textView al estar registrado en firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Quiero mostrar el correo del usuario en un `textView` que esta en un `navigationDrawer`, este es mi código pero me da error en el `+user.getMail`, dice en el +user:

> "Do not concatenate text displayed with setText. Use resource string
>   with placeholders." y en el getMail:"Method invocation 'getEmail' may
>   produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'"

al correr el programa no muestra nada

```
public class MainHeaderNav extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
 TextView MostrarCorreo;

@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nav_header_main);


    firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {

        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));


    }

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    MostrarCorreo = findViewById(R.id.MostrarCorreo);

    MostrarCorreo.setText("Hola"+user.getEmail());


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
}
```

Aclaro este es el código del `MainHeaderNavigation` en donde va la foto y el nombre de usuario del `navigationDrawer`.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias opciones, una de ellas es:

```
String saludo = "Hola";

if(user != null) {
    saludo = saludo.concat(" ").concat(user.getMail());
}

mostrarCorreo.setText(saludo);
```

Espero que te sirva. (º_º)

Comment: Argument 'user.getEmail()' might be null y al correrlo no me muestra el correo sigue en blanco el textview

Answer (score 0):

Cuidado, en principio lo que te está diciendo es que la variable "user" puede ser nula, y de hecho hay grandes probabilidades de que pase, debes hacer una validación luego de hacer esto:

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
if(user!=null){
    MostrarCorreo = findViewById(R.id.MostrarCorreo);
    String saludo = String.format(getString(R.string.hello_user), user.getEmail());
    MostrarCorreo.setText(saludo);
}
```

y en el directorio de strings creas un xml con el nombre hello_user

```
<string name="hello_user">Hola %s</string>
```

Exitos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, sigue sin mostarme el nombre, pero ya no me da null

Comment: Si el método retorna null, lo ideal sería que actualices el email utilizando el método updateProfile de la instancia del objeto FirebaseUser

Comment: Gracias, pero ya no me da null, solo no me muestra nada, sigue apareciendo en blanco, intentate el updateProfile